# ¿Cómo pasar variables por medio de un URL en PHP, usando GET?

Tags: php, url, get

Tengo este código en PHP donde almaceno el registro "CODIGO" dentro la variable $curso, lo que necesito es mandar esta VARIABLE dentro de la URL. He tratado de investigar en distintas páginas y aunque es algo tan sencillo como utilizar GET, no me está funcionando, gajes de dejar PHP por tanto tiempo en el olvido.

```
 <?php
      foreach (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
        tblcursos.CODIGOPLAN, 
        '-',
        tblcursos.NOMBRECURSO) AS codigo,
        tblcarreras.NOMBRECARRERA,
        tblcursosabiertos.CODIGOCURSO,
        tblcursosabiertoshorarios.NUMERO AS GRUPO,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[', tblcursosabiertoshorarios.DIA, '(', tblcursosabiertoshorarios.HORAINICIO, '-', tblcursosabiertoshorarios.HORAFIN,         ') ]  EA: ', tblcursosabiertoshorarios.CODIGOAULA) SEPARATOR '-') AS HORARIO,
        tblcursosabiertoshorarios.CODIGO
        
        FROM tblcursosabiertoshorarios
        INNER JOIN tblcursoabiertosgrupos
          ON tblcursosabiertoshorarios.CODIGO = tblcursoabiertosgrupos.CODIGO
          AND tblcursosabiertoshorarios.NUMERO = tblcursoabiertosgrupos.NUMERO
        INNER JOIN tblcursosabiertos tblcursosabiertos
          ON tblcursoabiertosgrupos.CODIGO = tblcursosabiertos.CODIGO
        INNER JOIN tblprofesor tblprofesor
          ON tblcursoabiertosgrupos.PROFESOR = tblprofesor.IDENTIFICACION
        INNER JOIN tblcursos tblcursos
          ON tblcursosabiertos.CODIGOCURSO = tblcursos.CODIGOCURSO
          AND tblcursos.CODIGOPLAN = tblcursosabiertos.CODIGOPLAN
        INNER JOIN tblplanesxcarrera
          ON tblcursosabiertos.CODIGOPLAN = tblplanesxcarrera.CODIGOPLAN
        INNER JOIN tblcarreras
          ON tblplanesxcarrera.CODIGOCARRERA = tblcarreras.CODIGOCARRERA
        WHERE tblcursosabiertos.ANNIO = '$annio'
        AND tblcursosabiertos.PERIODO LIKE '$periodo'
        AND tblprofesor.IDENTIFICACION LIKE '$ID'
        GROUP BY tblcursosabiertoshorarios.CODIGO,
               tblcursosabiertoshorarios.NUMERO,
               tblcarreras.NOMBRECARRERA
        ORDER BY tblcursoabiertosgrupos.PROFESOR DESC, tblcursosabiertos.CODIGOCURSO;") as $row){
        $codigo = $row['codigo'];
        $curso = $row['CODIGO'];
        $sql2 = "UPDATE tempLogin codigo = '$codigo' WHERE IDENTIFICACION == '$ID' AND session_id == '$session_id'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="align: center; width: auto;" class="btn btn-primary"><a style="color:white" href="listaEstudiantes.php?curso=<?echo $curso?>"><?php echo $codigo ?></a></span> <br> <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Aunque sí envía información, no el valor de la variable como tal. Aquí el código donde llamo la información con $_GET:

```
          <?php
      foreach (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT
        tblprofesor.IDENTIFICACION,
        CONCAT(tblprofesor.PRIMERNOMBRE,' ',tblprofesor.PRIMERAPELLIDO, ' ', tblprofesor.SEGUNDOAPELLIDO) AS NOMBRE
        FROM tblprofesor
        WHERE tblprofesor.IDENTIFICACION = '$ID';") as $row){ // aca puedes hacer la consulta e iterarla con each. ?> 
        <h4 style="text-align: center;">Facilitador: <?php echo $row['NOMBRE'] ?></h4>
        <h4 style="text-align: center;">Curso: <?php echo $_GET["curso"] ?></h4>
      <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Y aquí el resultado de dicho código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado esperado es: Curso: --> Valor devuelto en la consulta y que se almacenó en la variable <--

Comment: Arriba en tu url, curso=2019ITIIT1000.2PTICE-13. Y visita esa pagina

Comment: Disculpa, tal vez debí ser más específico, voy a reformular el resultado esperado; el valor de $curso es cambiante, está todo en la base de datos, puede ser ese u otro código de curso.

Comment: Bueno, donde sea que tengas botones para ir a otro curso

Comment: 'mirul/index.php?curso='.$variable_del_curso

El metodo $_GET['curso'] devuelve el valor de curso, es la unica forma posible...

Te faltaria hacer esto isset($_GET['curso']) para saber si te enviaron una variable o si esta vacio.

Comment: como es que haces una consulta a mysql y muestras toda esa info sin saber el curso al que pertenece

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en dos puntos:

1. tu codigo -> href="listaEstudiantes.php?curso="><?php echo $codigo ?

Estas pasando mal las variables GET,  `href="listaEstudiantes.php?curso=<?php echo $curso; ?>`
te falto el --> ;

2. en la pagina a donde envias tu varianle GET osea listaEstudiantes.php ahi debes preguntar si viene una variable get llamada cuso ---> isset($_GET['curso']) aca haces un echo de curso si te lo muestra es que si llego y todo ok y procedes con lo demas.